# Create Fixed Size Linked List in C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I have created a linked list in C that is used to store data which is then modified as required. In creating the linked list I have used the following

```
struct car_elements
{
  char car_rego[7];
  double time_parked;
  struct car_elements *next;
};

typedef struct car_elements car;

/* Defined as global variable to hold linked list */
car *head = NULL;

car *SetupCars()
{
  car *ptr = head;
  car *new_car = NULL;

  new_car = (car*) malloc(sizeof(car));
  if (!new_car)
  {
    printf("\nUnable to allocate memory!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  strcpy(new_car->car_rego, "empty");
  new_car->time_parked = time(NULL);
  new_car->next = NULL;

  if (ptr == NULL)
  {
    return (new_car);
  }
  else
  {
    while (ptr->next)
    {
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = new_car;
    return (head);
  }
}
```

From main I call the following to create the linked list

```
for(int i = 0; i<TOTAL_CARS; i++) {
   head = SetupCars(head);       
}
```

The problem is that now I have a memory leak - Is there a better way to create a fixed size linked list. At the end of the program running I can

```
free(head);
```

However I cannot call within SetupCars method

```
free(new_car);
```

I could create new_car as a global variable I guess and free it at the end of the program but I cannot help but feel there is a better way to do it. I don't think global variables are evil if used properly however I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: First of all - use valgrind with:
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ...

Comment: If you want a list with a fixed size why not use an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `car *head` as a global var. For `SetupCars`:

```
void SetupCars() /* void will do, unless you want a copy of the new "car" */
{
  car *new_car = NULL;
  new_car = malloc(sizeof *new_car); /* don't need to cast return value of malloc */

  /* do checks and setup new_car... */

  if (head == NULL) /* first element */
  {
     head = new_car;
  }
  else /* easier to add new_car as the FIRST element instead of last */
  { 
     new_car->next = head;
     head = new_car;
  }
}
```

From `main` you create the linked list the same way:

```
for(int i = 0; i<TOTAL_CARS; i++) {
   SetupCars(); /* without any arguments */
}
```

Then at the end, you loop through the list and free the objects. As [Manoj Pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240839/manoj-pandey) posted in his answer:

```
car *tofree;
car *ptr = head;
while(ptr) {
    tofree = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    free(tofree);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic - checked with valgrind and no memory leaks - All heap blocks were freed - no leaks are possible. I still have a lot to learn but I really appreciate your help. Perfect solution to the problem I was having.

Answer (score 4):

WHy not just free it at the end? SOmething like this:

```
car *tofree;
car *ptr = head;
while(ptr) {
    tofree = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    free(tofree);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a function to free the entire list, like:

```
void free_cars(car*p)  {
   while (p != NULL) {
      car* nextp = p->next;
      free (p);
      p = nextp;
   }
}
```

So you would call

```
free_cars (head);
head = NULL;
```

Perhaps even by having a macro

```
#define DELETE_CARS(CarsVar) do { \
   free_cars(CarsVar); CarsVar = NULL; } while(0)
```

then just write `DELETE_CARS(head);` later in your code.

And indeed, manual [memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) is painful, you need to avoid [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management). Tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can be helpful. And you could consider instead to use [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/), so use `GC_MALLOC` instead of `malloc` and don't bother freeing memory.... Read more about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Checked with valgrind and no memory leaks - you guys are great. Cheers